# Are there any languages where arguments come before the function?

Tags: function, syntax, programming-languages

That is to say, a language where function application looks like:

```
argument function
```

e.g.:

```
my_list length
```

Is there any particular reason why virtually all languages use a syntax like

```
function(argument) //brackets optional
```

?

Answer (score 2):

[Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)) is like that, as are some other stack-based languages, such as [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) calculators.

Both approaches are viable, though `f(x)` is more similar to established mathematical notation that [we've been using since 1734](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/FunctionMain.shtml).